# Firebase .update() returning undefined, is it not supposed to return the updated object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple update Firebase function, which looks like the following:

```js
export default async function updateStuff(firestore, id, data) {
    const stuff = await firestore
        .collection('Stuff')
        .doc(id)
        .update(data)
    
    console.log('updated stuff:', stuff) // Will always be undefined, despite working.
}
```

The update is working as expected and everything, however, once the Promise goes through all I have is `undefined`. I could have sworn that it once returned the actual entry that was updated with its updated values, does it not do so anymore?

Is there something that could be done to verify that it has been in fact updating without doing a whole separate `.get()` call after the update?

I can't find the proper `update()` API docs, but I did as stated on this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#receive_a_promise):

> To know when your data is committed to the Firebase Realtime Database server, you can use a Promise. Both set() and update() can return a Promise you can use to know when the write is committed to the database.

Is it just a `Promise<void>` with no other information on the updated object? And I can assume it will throw if it fails? I just seems counter-productive for an update API to have to keep refetching values once the operation is done.

Comment: Be careful to not confuse Cloud Firestore and the Realtime Database. They have different APIs and behaviours. See the Cloud Firestore reference for [`update()` here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) (you linked to the Realtime Database docs)

Comment: @samthecodingman thanks, I was scattering to find that exact page. I will keep that in mind for future issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the reference documentation for [`DocumentReference.update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update), you'll see that it returns `Promise<void>`.

If you need the updated data, you'll need to `get()` that in a separate call. If you update multiple documents, you may need multiple `get()` calls too.

The promise will indeed be rejected when the operation fails.

Comment: Thanks! That is the page I couldn't seem to find. Will bookmark that and keep it noted. Suppose I really just thought it was more common practice to return the updated object upon update and it felt like it would be a bit counterproductive to have to refetch things every time.

Comment: @theJuls While it may seem that way to not return any data, if I wanted to only update the user's name in their profile document I could call `update('name', 'John Doe')` or `update({'name': 'John Doe'})`. This would be a simple document write operation sent off to the server. If it did return the document data in this call, not only do I need to wait for the data to be sent back, I would be billed for a document read and bandwidth that I never needed - which I would argue is counterproductive. It's easier to explicitly use `get()` when needed, which is often locally cached anyway.

Comment: If you did want an update operation that returned the data in the same call, you could, albeit not recommended, wrap your call around a [`Transaction`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction) operation (you can read up on that [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions)).

Comment: I had to double check the return value too, to learn what it returns. I'm not sure why the team chose to implement like they did, but assume they had valid reasons for that. Sam's first comment is a good example of some considerations that might play into it.